# Passing parameters in a customized OpenAI gym environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have a problem with a customized OpenAI gym environment. In my implementation I have the following initialization:

```html
 def __init__(self, df):
```

This means that I need to pass an extra argument (a data frame) when I call `gym.make()`. I read that exists two different solutions: the first one consists of modify the `register` function when I create the environment, the second one consists of create an extra initialization method in the customized env and access it in order to pass the extra argument. No one of the proposed solutions works for me. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `__init__()` method to:

```
    class CustomEnv(gym.Env):    
      def __init__(self, df):
        super(CustomEnv, self).__init__()
        # you are ready to use your df
```

and use your environment like this:

```
env = gym.make('CustomEnv-v0', df=df)
```